# Can sibling in-laws have romantic relationships in the Sims 2

Tags: the-sims-2

In the Sims 2, is it possible for siblings in-law to have romantic relationships.
Here's a scenario, just in case Sibling in-law isn't the correct term:

I have a man, let's call him Andy to be simple. Andy has married a woman -- let's say Betty. Andy has a brother (an adult) called Charlie. Can Charlie and Betty do anything romantic? That is, can someone be romantic with his brother's wife? Charlie and Betty aren't related at all, and on the Sims family tree they do not appear related. However, I can't seem to get kissing or anything to come up.

So that's my question. Can Charlie get with his brother's wife?

EDIT: Should point out, this is for the PC, NOT console.

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue - is their relationship score high enough?

Comment: @MacCooper - Its not possible with the default relationship.

Comment: Ramhound, just to clarify: Are you saying, not without hacks or mods? Just making sure.

Comment: Heh. Yeah, Ender. She is :) Didn't seem to be working, so I used Kennedy Kox instead xD Still interested if anyone knows the answer though, there's still time and always more sim lives to warp.

Comment: What's Betty's aspiration? As I recall, Family sims were much less likely to accept romantic attention from another sim if they are married. Romance sims, on the other hand, will gleefully acquire multiple lovers. I don't remember ever testing this specific situation, but I did create a family of eight brothers, had them all fall in love with the same sim, and turned them loose in the same household to watch the chaos.